# Why has one real always the value of one other real?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran, intel-fortran

I observed some strange behavior of two Values in my Fortran program.

A function `abstand_flex` is called several times from different subroutines, two of the interface values, which are only intented out, have always the same value. If the value of one changes, the value of the other changes too.

Here is an excerpt:

```
Subroutine foo (...)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, DECORATE, ALIAS :: walzspalt
implicit none
...
real(8), allocatable, dimension(:) :: x_dis,y_dis,z_dis,erg,ti,ri,r_profiel
integer :: npunkte,n_pkt
real(8), allocatable, dimension(:) :: ti,ri
real(8), dimension(3) :: P,R,HP,pkt,RP
real(8) :: t,dist_lager,Abstand_flex
real(8), parameter :: pi=Dacos(-1.d0)
real(8), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: wrandi
real(8), dimension(n_pkt) :: r_arr,x_arr
...
allocate(x_dis(2*npunkte+1),y_dis(2*npunkte+1),z_dis(2*npunkte+1))
allocate(erg(2*npunkte+1),ti(2*npunkte+1),wrandi(3,2*npunkte+1),ri(2*npunkte+1))

call test_points(p_dis,r_dis,x_dis,y_dis,z_dis,npunkte,P,x_min+(l_ges*0.05d0),l_ges-2*(l_ges*0.05d0))

do i=1, 2*npunkte+1

    pkt(1)=x_dis(i)
    pkt(2)=y_dis(i)
    pkt(3)=z_dis(i)
    erg(i)=Abstand_flex(pkt,P,R,r_arr,x_arr,n_pkt,ti(i),wrandi(1:3,i),ri(i))
end do
...
end subroutine foo
```

the function:

```
real(8) function Abstand_flex(pkt,P,R,r_arr,x_arr,npunkte,t,w_rand,ri)
integer npunkte
real(8), intent(in), dimension(npunkte) :: r_arr,x_arr
real(8), dimension(3), intent(in) :: P,R,pkt
real(8) :: k,ri2,t_save
real(8), dimension(3) :: erg_kreuz
real(8), dimension(3) :: p_1,r_1,p_tmp
real(8), dimension(3), intent (out) :: w_rand
real(8), dimension(3) :: p_2,r_2, p_d_1,p_d_2,r_d_1,erg_kreuz2   !
real(8) :: t2,dist_neu
real(8), intent(out) :: ri,t
real(8), parameter :: pi=Dacos(-1.0d0)
integer :: i,l
...
t=-(r(1)*p_tmp(1)+r(2)*p_tmp(2)+r(3)*p_tmp(3)) / (r(1)*r(1)+r(2)*r(2)+r(3)*r(3))

...
ri=(t-x_arr(i))/(x_arr(i+1)-x_arr(i))*(r_arr(i+1)-r_arr(i))+r_arr(i)

...
end function Abstand_flex
```

`t` and `ri` have always the same Value.

The strange thing is, when I add `ti=0.0d0` after allocating `ti`, this error vanishes. And everything behaves nicely.

I tried to export this function to another program to trigger this error and publish a compilable example, but the minimized program works just fine and doesn’t show such behavior.

Compiler: Intel Fortran Compiler XE 13.1 with Visual Studio 2010.
The subroutine and the function are compiled to a DLL file. A Fortran Main opens a input file, calls the DLL file, and writes the results.

I can see this behavior with the Debug functions of Visual Studio and by writing the values to the command prompt.

Comment: I think you should show more code. The complete headers at the very least. Are the procedures in a module?

Comment: No Modules. I'll add more code

Comment: Per your description, the problem is somewhere else. And the best thing to do in the first place is to add some compiling option that will trigger memory issues like checking array bounds, and eventually run in a debugger.

Comment: Is R (= r) initialized before entering Abstand_flex()?

Comment: @innoSPG i have `debug:full`, `check:all`.  And i run within Visual Studio with single step execution so i can follow the values.

Comment: @roygvib on entering Abstand_flex() `pkt,P,R,r_arr,x_arr,n_pkt` are set to some calculated values.

Comment: Does adding "implicit none" at the top of Abstand_flex() make some difference...? For gfortran, it is useful to put options like -fcheck=all -finit-real=snan -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero -fbacktrace -g -Wall -Wuninitialized etc, etc, but I'm not sure about ifort13...

Comment: You will have to prepare a MCVE. Minimal code that still reproduces the problem. Create a copy and delete mercilessly, bu always check that the problem is still there. If it disappeared, you have a good chance that what you deleted is connected to the error.

Comment: @roygvib seems i deleted `implicit none` while adding more code. I'll fix this. For ifort i have activated most of the debug flags. there seems toba no problem.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm on it now.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry, i overlooked it completly. It's `t` and `ri`. I'll Update the Question.